# explain this python3 vs python behavior of sys.stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have to write a code that somehow works for both python versions and I can't understand the behavior of the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
print("input: ", end="")
f = sys.stdin.readline()
print(f)
```

When I run the code with python2 it behaves like I expect:

```
$ python2 test_input.py 
input: foo bar
foo bar
```

When I run the code with python3 it behaves strange. It first reads the input
and then prints the prompt:

```
$ python3 test_input.py 
foo bar
input: foo bar
```

Can you explain this and suggest a fix?

Comment: The I/O subsystem in Python 3 is a complete overhaul (see the `io` module, available in Python 2 as well), so it is no suprise that flushing behaviour may have changed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, actually, the solution by Dietrich Epp works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how would you do it?

Comment: have you tried `from six.moves import input; print("*" + input("input: "))`?
`

Comment: If you are using sys.stdin.readline to avoid the `rawinput` to `input` change, put `try: input=rawinput\nexcept NameError: pass`. at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your `flush()` and `print()` backwards.  Here is the correct order:

```
# First, write to stdout
print("input: ", end="")
# Then, flush all data in the stdout buffer
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I think that that was the *point*. The OP shows that `stdout` has been flushed manually first, after which the difference in behaviour is unexpected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: What would the point be of calling `flush()` with nothing in the buffer?

Comment: To produce a minimal, verifiable test case that demonstrates the behaviour?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: For what?  For demonstrating that flushing an empty buffer is pointless?

Comment: For demonstrating that the buffer is definitely empty.

Comment: It is already known that the buffer is empty, because the program is reproduced in its entirety, and the buffer is empty at program startup.

Comment: And perhaps the OP did not trust that assumption. The question is still about *why there is a difference*. If *remove* the flush call, older Python versions will still behave differently from Python 3.3 and up.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that CPython 2  uses C stdio to implement standard streams such as `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` (used by `print()`) while Python 3 reimplements IO on top of system API e.g., open, read, write on POSIX.

To avoid thinking about how `print()` is implemented, the same issue occurs if `sys.stdout` is used directly:

```
# __main__.py
import sys

sys.stdout.write("input: ")
f = sys.stdin.readline()
sys.stdout.write("*" + f)
```

On Python 3 `"input: "` is not printed before the `readline()` call:

```
$ python2 .
input: foo bar
*foo bar
$ python3 .
foo bar
input: *foo bar
```

In C, `stdout` is flushed before reading any input in the interactive case (it is undefined behavior if an output operation is followed by an input operation on the same update stream without `fflush()` in between). This C program prints `"input: "` before asking for input as expected:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int main(void) {
  char buf[MAXLEN] = {0};

  fputs("input: ", stdout);
  if (!fgets(buf, MAXLEN, stdin))
    return 1;

  fputs(buf, stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

That is why the workaround: calling `sys.stdout.flush()` before `sys.stdin.readline()` [suggested by @Dietrich Epp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26449390/4279) works.

It is a deficiency in Python 3 implementation. stdout shall be flushed by default before reading from stdin if both point to the same place (`os.path.samefile(sys.stdout.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())` e.g., if both tty). You could [report the issue at Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.3 the `flush` keyword was added to the [`print()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> *Changed in version 3.3*: Added the flush keyword argument.

In versions before 3.3, the `print()` function would *always* flush, even when using `end=''`. Your exact behaviour also reproduced using Python 3.2:

```
$ python3.2 test.py 
foo bar
input: foo bar
```

To get the same behaviour, flush in Python 3.3:

```
try:
    print("input: ", end="", flush=True)
except TypeError:
    print("input: ", end="")
```

or use `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print()` calls on Python 3.3 or up.

Comment: "Or use `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print()` calls"... weren't you *complaining* about that advice in my answer?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I am complaining about your *diagnosis*. I'm saying the flush was put first **deliberately**. I never said it wouldn't solve the problem. The OP is asking for us to explain **why** there is a difference between Py 2 and Py 3.